# Push only values of an object array into another array

Tags: javascript

I am looking to push only the values of `ObjArray` into another array called `Array`.

```
var Array = [];

var ObjArray = [{item1 : 'Foo'}, {item2 : 'Bar'}];

// Push Values from ObjArray into Array

pushValues(ObjArray, Array);
```

The expected output would be `Array` having only `['Foo', 'Bar']`

Thanks!

edit: Sorry. I am asking how to push all values from `ObjArray` into `Array`.

Comment: What makes your keys as `item1, item2..` ?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc - Names of keys are not identical to use `Arraay#map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

And [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values.

As you have single value in the object use `[0]` to return that.

```js
var ObjArray = [{item1 : 'Foo'}, {item2 : 'Bar'}];
var array = ObjArray.map(i => Object.values(i)[0]);
console.log(array);
```

Using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and `push()`

```js
var array = [];
var ObjArray = [{item1 : 'Foo'}, {item2 : 'Bar'}];
for(var i of ObjArray){
  array.push(Object.values(i)[0]);
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objects have multiple key-value pairs within them you can use a combination of [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like so:

```js
const objArray = [{a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}, {c : 'baz'}];
const arr = objArray.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(arr); // ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

However, do note, [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) does have [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility), and so, if you need something a little more compatible, you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead:

```js
const objArray = [{a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}, {c : 'baz'}];
const arr = objArray.reduce((a, o) => [...a, ...Object.values(o)], []);

console.log(arr); // ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```